# Find if any line of a file is a subset of data in another file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

I have a file `file1.txt` with the following data:

```
MIME_HTML_ONLY
SUSPICIOUS_RECIPS
SORTED_RECIPS
HFILTER_HELO_5
```

and another file `file2.txt` with lines as:

```
HFILTER_FROM_BOUNCE FORGED_OUTLOOK_HTML
SORTED_RECIPS HFILTER_HELO_5
MIME_HTML_ONLY HFILTER_FROM_BOUNCE
SUSPICIOUS_RECIPS ANY_OTHER_WORD
:
:
```

I want to find all the lines in `file2.txt` who's data (all the words of that line) is the subset of the data present in `file1.txt`

For e.g the ***output*** above should be the line :
`SORTED_RECIPS HFILTER_HELO_5`

Now I can loop through and read individual lines of `file2.txt` and see if its the subset of `file1.txt`. But i've have to do this for say a 1000 different `file1.txt's`. So looping through individual lines of `file2.txt` for every `file1.txt`is very slow. Is there any efficient way to do this using `awk`  `sed` `grep` ?

Comment: For 1000 different `file1.txt's`, do you want to know exactly which `file1.txt` is matching against `file2.txt`?  or just want to know whether or not there's matching `file1.txt`?

Comment: Actually for any `file1.txt`, i just want to know if there's any line in `file2.txt` that's the subset of data in `file1.txt`(as mentioned above). I've to check this condition for all the other 1000 `file1.txt's` and exactly want to know the file, since i'm performing later operations with that `file1.txt`. So i'll probably loop through them which isn't the issue once i get to know the solution.

Comment: Ok.  IMHO it would suffice to just loop over 1000 `file1.txt's` running the script in my answer, if `file2.txt` contains less than 1M lines.  Otherwise it would be better to find way to compile all `file1.txt's` into one sed/awk script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following script is compiling `file1.txt` into a single regex for `grep -E`.

```
#!/bin/sh
regex="^($(awk '{printf $0"|"}' $1) )+\$"
grep -E "$regex" $2
```

Usage:

```
$ ./script.sh file1.txt file2.txt 
SORTED_RECIPS HFILTER_HELO_5
```

`$regex` is compiled from `file1.txt` as follows:

```
^(ME_HTML_ONLY|SUSPICIOUS_RECIPS|SORTED_RECIPS|HFILTER_HELO_5| )+$
```

For thousands of `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` with millions of lines, it would be better to compile all of `file1.txt's` into a single awk program with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i; do
        regex="^($(awk '{printf $0"|"}' $i) )+\$"
        echo "/$regex/ { print \"$i: \"\$0 }"
done
```

For example (`file1.txt's` are named as `match1.txt` `match2.txt` `match3.txt`):

```
$ ./script2.sh match*.txt 
/^(ME_HTML_ONLY|SUSPICIOUS_RECIPS|SORTED_RECIPS|HFILTER_HELO_5| )+$/ { print "match1.txt: "$0 }
/^(HFILTER_FROM_BOUNCE|FORGED_OUTLOOK_HTML|ANY_OTHER_WORD| )+$/ { print "match2.txt: "$0 }
/^(SORTED_RECIPS|HFILTER_HELO_5|MIME_HTML_ONLY|HFILTER_FROM_BOUNCE| )+$/ { print "match3.txt: "$0 }

$ ./script2.sh match*.txt >match.awk
$ awk -f match.awk file2.txt 
match2.txt: HFILTER_FROM_BOUNCE FORGED_OUTLOOK_HTML
match1.txt: SORTED_RECIPS HFILTER_HELO_5
match3.txt: SORTED_RECIPS HFILTER_HELO_5
match3.txt: MIME_HTML_ONLY HFILTER_FROM_BOUNCE
```

Comment: That is indeed a great converting the contents of file into a regex. Totally worked. I think looping through the file would suffice. Sucks that i can't upvote. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @awhitesong Updated, just for the case you have `file2.txt` with millions of lines.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'FNR == NR && $0 !~ /^[[:blank:]]*$/ { Dict[$0] = 1 }
     FNR != NR {
        i = 1
        while( i <= NF && Dict[ $i] == 1) i++
        if( i > NF) print
        }
    ' File1.txt File2.txt
```

- generic, non dependant to file2 number of field/word per line
- work with sorted and unsorted content of both file
- use memory to load first file in *Dictionnary* so maybe not the best if huge number of word to validate
- files order to provide to awk is mandatory

  - 1st is dictionnary reference
  - any (at least 1) other are file to filter

**Concept:**

- load each word in a array using the value as index

  - taking 1 as value (unassigned have 0 by default)
  - from first file [where FNR (file record number) = NR (record number since first opened file) and a record is, by default, a line in awk]
  - there is a filter on empty line (no character or only space)
- initialise a counter (i)
- compare each field (word here due to space separator by default) to his equivalent in Dictionnary. If exist (value = 1), loop to next field and increment a counter (i)
- after the loop, if the counter (i) is bigger than the number of field (word), all word are matching, we print the line
- loop to next line entry